# Can Bootstrap 4 split inputfield form input to save on width on narrow devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My webapp currently has a number of pages containing forms with many inputs like the one below

[image: Without Boostrap]

Please note that the codes uses table/tr/td and originally the input field was always to the right of the input field as it still is with the first two options. However I changed input where the combined field width was wide to try and avoid horizontal scrolling on tablet/phone devices. Ideally i would like it to be to the right if there is enough room (such as on a computer) to avoid unnecessary vertical scrolling but indent below when not enough  since better to have vertical scrolling rather than horizontal scrolling.

This is one reason I have moved to *Bootstrap* to try and achieve this. I found 
that with the following

```
<div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <label class="input-group-text" id="selectfolderaddon">
                            Selected Folder 
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div aria-describedby="selectfolderaddon">
                        <input type="text" name="folder" id="folder" class="form-control" value="C:\Users\Paul\Music\AKO">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

That it would be left/right when enough space but then go below each other when not enough space as the next two screenshots show.

[image: Wide, sing by side]

Like this

[image: Narrow, below each other]

This is good, but it would be better if the input field would indent on the left handside a bit when dropped to the next line, **is this possible** ?

I then tried with a *Select* but this would not split, is that a bug in my code, Bootstrap code or is it intentional

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, as you surmised, a bug in your code.  The structure for `input-group` is pretty rigid... your input element cannot be wrapped in the `<div>` you're using; it interferes with Bootstrap's structure.

If we simply remove your wrapper element and apply `aria-describedby="selectfolderaddon"` to the actual input field the `input-group` component functions as expected.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <label class="input-group-text" id="selectfolderaddon">Selected Folder </label>
  </div>

  <input type="text" name="folder" id="folder" class="form-control" value="C:\Users\Paul\Music\AKO" aria-describedby="selectfolderaddon">
</div>
```

In the above snippet the `input-group-prepend` will always appear to the left, and the `form-control` enhanced `<input>` will shrink to fit the remaining available space.  Added bonus; you restore the UI/UX functionality where the two items are connected.  With the wrapper you were adding the default rounded edges of Bootstrap's `<input>` CSS were being applied on all borders.

Comment: I can see the bug now, but actually I was happy with it wrapping when it got narrower, thats what I wanted it to do ! The bug I was concerned with was the selectbox not wrapping. With the fix it does still wrap but only when there is no space left for the input as well - https://jsfiddle.net/paultaylor/3pcezx1r/ So I suppose its not possible to make it automtically wrap then ident.

Comment: I cannot comment on your `<select>` concern as you haven't shown that code.  If you want your input field not to take up 100% of the available space you can remove `form-control` from its class definitions. You might want to add a padding utility class in its place though as otherwise the text will appear near the very edge.

Comment: Forget about the select the key question was wil it wrap when device width too small

Comment: okay I am marking correct as you did spot a bug, although that wasn't exactly my question.

Comment: The short of your question is "No". `input-group` binds those elements together regardless of whether it would be more convenient to collapse them at certain breakpoints.  That's the trade off for treating labels in this fashion instead of with `col-form-label` and a column size.